# JAR Manifest Main-Class relative or absolute?

Tags: java

I am struggling to find confirmation across JAR Manifest documentation, but I am wondering if your entry point was contained in './src/java/main/Program.java' (where ./ is the root directory for your project) for instance would your JAR Manifest file look like this (where the file is located in your root)?

```
Main-Class: src.java.main.Program
```

If this is the case, what if your Manifest was located in some subdirectory such as './lib', would it then still be the same as above or would it be something else?

EDIT: I am asking this in relation to using Ant to build JAR files from some given project, where we need to specify to the  command where to find the entry point to the project.

Comment: The fully qualified class name is a **logicial name** of the class. How this maps to a path (either inside a jar or outside) is a separate task, that's unrelated to this. You're **not** providing a *path* here, but a *name*.

Comment: (1) The `Main-Class` is neither relative not absolute. It isn't a filename at all. It is a fully-qualified class name, including its package. (2) The Manifest file itself can only be in one place: `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`, in the JAR file; where it is in the file system is irrelevant. Your questions are based on misconceptions.

Comment: I am talking about the Manifest file that I need to create for Ant build scripts to read through and understand where the entry-point for the JAR file is when such an artefact is created. I understand what you are saying that once the JAR file is created, the Manifest is stored in the one and only possible directory, but I have tried to make clear in the edit to my question that is not what I am referring to.

Answer (score 0):

The path to the manifest file is fixed, [it can’t be moved to a subdirectory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/defman.html):

> When you create a JAR file, it automatically receives a default manifest file. There can be only one manifest file in an archive, and it always has the pathname
>
> ```
> META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
> ```

The name of the main class always needs to be the fully-qualified class name. It can’t be unqualified and, since it isn’t a path, it can’t be “relative”. But it *usually* corresponds to the absolute resource path of the main class file inside the JAR.

One exception, as noted in the comments, is for multi-release JARs (with `Multi-Release: true` specified in the manifest). In that case, the class resources for additional versions are located in a versioned subfolder inside the JAR file — but the *manifest* is still in the same, fixed location.

Note also that, unlike in your example, the fully-qualified class name is unlikely to start with `src.java.main`. Instead, it looks like the (garbled) folder structure of our Java source files (which are conventionally located in a subfolder of `src/main/java`). The actual fully-qualified class name should generally correspond to a folder path *below that path* (e.g. `com.your-company.project.Main` might correspond to the file `src/main/java/com/your-company/project/Main.java`). It is given by the name of the package plus the simple name of the class, separated by a dot.

For example, consider a class `Test` in `Test.java`:

```
package me.klmr.project;

class Test { … }
```

The fully-qualified class name of `Test` is `me.klmr.project.Test`, regardless of the path at which `Test.java` is stored (but the conventional path would be `src/main/java/me/klmr/project/Test.java`, relative to the project root).

Comment: I see that I should have probably specified that I was asking in relation to using Ant to build a JAR file from my project (when using the command <jar />). For this command we need to let Ant know where to find the entry point to the program.

Comment: In some cases (such as multi-release jar files) the actual class that will get executed might *not* be placed in the simple `/foo/Bar.class` space, but actually somewhere like `META-INF/versions/9/foo/Bar.class`, but the name given in the manifest will still just be the FQCN.

Comment: @James: the entry point is **always** just given as a fully qualified class name. Mapping that onto some path is a separate task.

Comment: So it would always be (in the case of specifying for my Ant build, for the example directory I have given) `src.java.main.Program`?

Comment: @James: that's highly unlikely. What's the `package`  statement of your class? And what's the local name? Combine those and you get `some.package.Class`. That they are in `src/main/java` inside your project is just organization in your code. The **name** still doesn't contain those (yes, you *could* have a package called `src.main.java`, but that's highly unusual and if you do, then that's probably a misconfiguration somewhere).

Comment: How might you go about discovering the FQN of some given `.java` file? Most resources online are catered towards automatically designed directory structures such as those generated by Maven, but I have created my directory in a custom structure and am wondering how my custom alterations impacts on things such as this FQN? It appears you are saying that I could put my entry point in any random directory and the FQN would remain the same?

Comment: @James The fully-qualified name is given by the package declaration + the class name. In other words, it’s determined by the code you write. As for directory structure of your source code, it’s a fairly bad idea to deviate from the established Java norm here (which is *not* just a Maven norm). — Anyway, the directory structure of the `.class` files is a *different matter*. It *must* in general follow the FQCN.